# How to update a jQuery function to replace the source and not return?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Given the following plugin: https://github.com/Marak/jquery.emoticon.js

How does the author expect you to use the below?

```
$.fn.emoticon = function(theText) {
    var imagePath = "emotes/"; 
    var newText = theText;
    for( var a in emoticons.emoticon ) {
        emoticon = emoticons.emoticon[a];
        for( var emote in emoticon.emotes ) {

            emote = RegExp.escape(emote);
            newText = newText.replace( new RegExp( emote, 'gi' ), '<img src="'+imagePath + emoticon.image + '" />');
        }
    }
    return newText;
};
```

If I run:

```
$('body').emoticon('Hello :0 World')
```

It returns:

```
"Hello <img src="emotes/shock.png" /> World"
```

Is there a way to actually have it replace the element passed? As in updating where it finds a match? Kind of like how tipsy you apply tipsy to the element you want: `$('#example-1').tipsy();`

Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: "this" in this context would probably be the element in question

Comment: right but how can I update to actually replace what I pass?

Comment: Try using `$(this).replace(newElement);` perhaps?

Comment: It looks like a poor plugin to me. The usage does not make any sense. It just cares about the text passed to it, not the jQuery selector (which is totally ignored). I would either look for another plugin or create one by yourself (based on his search/replace method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad jquery plugin as roberkules said, this function below will replace the html of the jquery element and then returns this (the jquery elements) to allow chaining.

```
$.fn.emoticon = function(theText) {
    var imagePath = "emotes/"; 
    var newText = theText;
    for( var a in emoticons.emoticon ) {
        emoticon = emoticons.emoticon[a];
        for( var emote in emoticon.emotes ) {
            emote = RegExp.escape(emote);
            newText = newText.replace( new RegExp( emote, 'gi' ), '<img src="'+imagePath + emoticon.image + '" />');
        }
    }
    return this.each(function() {           
        $(this).html(newText);
    });
};
```

So with html:

```
<body></boby>
```

Running

```
$('body').emoticon('Hello :0 World');
```

Would result in the function returning $('body') and the html being:

```
<body>Hello <img src="emotes/shock.png" /> World</boby>
```

Comment: Function should also probably be wrapped, something like (function($){ /* function goes here */ })(jQuery);